# require is not define / module.exports is not define with node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, module, routes

After receveing help about using Express, I continued to follow tutorials about Node.js. I'm at a point where i'm building my own routes in controllers to create a REST API. I have two files, app.js and /controllers/account-api.js.

Here's my app.js shortened (i deleted the parts that were not used my my test), and the line that is returning me some issues.

```
import express from 'express';
import exphbs from 'express-handlebars';
import * as accountApiRoutes from './controllers/account-controller.js';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(accountApiRoutes); // ISSUE HERE, i tried ('/account-api', accountApiRoutes) too

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    res.redirect('/server-home');
});

app.get('/server-home', function(req, res)
{
    res.render('server-home');

});

app.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Express Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

And here's my ./controllers/account-api.js shortened again to give the main elements that causes the issue :

```
import express from 'express';

const apiRouter = express.Router(); //ISSUE HERE

var accounts = [];

accounts.push( { code: 1, name: 'Pierrette', adress: 'Sur la Lune'} );

// =========== API ROUTES =========== //
// GET
apiRouter.route('/produit-api/produit/:code')
.get( function(req, res, next) {
    var codeSended = req.params.code;
    var account = findAccountInArrayByCode(codeSended);
   res.send(account);
});


// =========== METHODS AND FUNCTIONS =========== //
// GET
function findAllAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

function findAccountInArrayByCode(codeSended) {
    var accountFound = null;
    for(i in accounts)
    {
        if(accounts[i].code === codeSended)
        {
            accountFound = accounts[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return accountFound;
}

module.exports = { //ISSUE HERE
    getApiRouter: function() {
        const apiRouteur = express.Router();
        return apiRouter;
    }
}
```

The problem is.. This code returns me "module" is not defined.
I use Node.JS with Express and Handlebars.

For what I saw online, when using "app.use", it requires a function. And module.exports too. I tried various solutions, like this one :

account-api.js

```
const apiRouter = function() { return express.Router() }
...
module.exports = apiRouteur;
```

The problem is that it changes the type of apiRouteur, when calling apiRouteur.get from IRouter to () => Router, and the routes break.

I don't know how to arrange the code to make the module.exports returning a function that works, or if the problem is not even about the type of value returned, but if I'm missing dependancies, etc...

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :** With the explanations I got, I replaced all my ES6 calls to commonjs imports. But it doesn't solve the problem. Now it's "require" that's not define.

I was stuck firstly by "require is not defined", and the solution I was given by reading old SO threads about it, the answer was regularly to use ES6 imports...
ack to the begining I guess ! Maybe I miss something in my project?

Comment: For a reason I don't understand, the "Hi all !" disappeared. So Hi, if you read this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line `app.use(accountApiRoutes);` and you are using a mix of ES6 and commonjs modules.

To fix the module imports (as you are using `.js` files not `.mjs`) change all your ES6 imports i.e `import * as xyz` imports to commonjs imports `const x = require('...');`

The `accountApiRoutes` is an object but not a `Router` object.
To fix you just need to pass the router object to the `app.use` function.

So you will need to make a couple of changes based on what you have supplied above.

```
// ./controllers/account-api.js
const express = require('express');
...

module.exports = { //ISSUE HERE
    getApiRouter: function() {
        return apiRouter; // you have already defined the router you don't need to recreate it
    }
}
```

Properly pass the `Router` object to the express app.

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const accountApiRoutes = require('./controllers/account-controller.js');

...
app.use(accountApiRoutes.getApiRouter());
```

You could also just set `module.exports` to your configured router in your `account-api.js` and then you could pass it directly to `app.use` as you have already done in your server above. Either way should work. To can do that as follows:

```
// ./controllers/account-api.js
const express = require('express');
...
module.exports = apiRouter;
```

And in your server.js

```
const accountRouter = require('./controllers/account-controller.js');
app.use(accountRouter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! What the second solution looks like? I'm trying the first solution but I get "module is not defined" again. I run the "node app.js" line. It's like my program doesn't even know the inscruction. Do I miss something?

Comment: Edit : I figured myself the second solution. But same error :(

Comment: I'm on VSC terminal, using "node app.js" command line. Node -v returns me v14.15.1 . I installed Typescript but i don't have any .ts file and don't use if at the moment. Express version is 4.17.1

Comment: updated my answer to address the ES6 module imports vs commonjs imports

Comment: And then I'm back again to the "require" is not defined :( 
That's why I was using ES6 module import, because require wasn't working for me. I begin to think definitely I'm missing something really important here.